# Magento - Zoom on category pages / other pages than product view?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, zooming

Has anyone found a good way / module to enable zooming in on images in either the grid or list mode on the category view pages?  I have a client who wants that, and also the ability to zoom in on the image for any featured products we place on the home page individually.

I know it's possible (by creating multiple zoom js instances, etc), but am wondering if this particular wheel has already been invented - my searching so far has not turned up anything, and I'm trying to keep the hours down here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this yourself I'm afraid, using js libraries of course which is already doing most the work! As you already pointed out you need to create multiple zoom instances on the bits you want to have zoom. Really shouldn't take too long. Think about people with older browsers and machines though, creating lots of these instances on page (e.g. 50-100 product list) load may effect the performance of the site for some users and browsers. Maybe a hover over to initiate the zoom instance would alleviate this problem, or a simple hover over pop up instead of zoom.